how do I form an http response that includes both html to be rendered by the browser AND binary data to be downloaded?
In response to a POST request, I'd like to send an http response that includes BOTH html to be rendered by the browser AND binary data to be downloaded by the browser.  When the browser receives that response, I'd like it to render the html and download the binary data.
How do I form the http response to make that happen?
A couple of notes...

This thread asks about the same problem, but the solution offered is not what I'm looking for because it only shows the data in the html rendered by the browser.  I want the binary data I send to be downloaded, while the html is rendered on its own.

My understanding from MDN is that the Downloads browser API is not supported by Safari.  Since I want to serve users using Safari, I don't think sending the data as an object in javascript as part of the page and then providing a button on the page to download the data  (which works by calling the Downloads API) is an option here.  If there IS some sort of browser API that can download arbitrary objects to the host machine in response to events that IS supported by all current browsers, please let me know!

I've tagged this with content-types, because I'm guessing the solution involves some sort of magic with the content-type header (?)


Thanks!!!

You aren't finding a direct solution because there isn't one. You'll need to use a workaround, such as the one in the linked thread paired with some form of causing a download to begin after the page loads with a click to begin download fallback.

Why do you want this? Why does it need to be 1 HTTP response? I don't see how the downloads API makes a difference here because there would still be a second request.

Evert, I need to respond to requests by users for large subsets of data from a DB, delivered as binary files (e.g. RData, dta, sav). Because these binary files will be large I don't want to store them in my DB.  Instead, I want to form them on demand using server-side code triggered by a POST request and send them back in a response to the POST.  Basically, the response to the post request should include the binary file and redirect the user to a page that alerts the user that their requested file is being successfully delivered.

Couldn’t you first direct to the HTML page, then trigger the redirect to the binary download? This is what many major software packages’ download pages do to achieve a similar effect

I have a solution to this, which I'll get to...But first I want to provide some context, in hopes of saving others the trouble of thinking there must be a better way of solving the problem that prompted this post in the first place, and then spending time googling for better way when there really isn't one.
I posted this question because (1) I have an API that fields requests for resources that are generated by my server-side code on the fly, then returned as blobs, (2) I wanted to offer users a web interface that would allow then to submit requests to that API through a button click and have their browsers respond by downloading the blob once delivered, and (3) the data returned by the API is pretty large and the server-side code that constructs the resource in response to a request is complicated, so there will be substantial latency for users between button click and download.
Of course, there is a straightforward way to offer users the ability to fetch and download a blob returned by an API with a click: Just put an <a> tag in the front end, with the href pointing to the API endpoint and the download attribute present.  But this seems to me a bad fit for my particular case for two reasons:  First, clicking an <a> sends a GET to the API, but because the request I want to fill triggers the creation of a resource (not just the delivery of an already existing resource), 'GET' is the wrong verb.  Second, because of the long latency in my case between button click and download, I want more fine-grained control in the frontend over the behavior of the UI during the wait than I know how to get with an simple <a> tag.  At first, I thought the way to handle this was to point the href to an endpoint that would respond with both UI that would keep the user informed during the wait and the blob the user had request when it was ready (hence the original question in this thread).  But as commenter Kevin B correctly says, responding with both UI and a blob is not a thing in HTTP is equipped to do.
What IS a standard thing is a <button> with a click handler that sends a POST request and displays feedback to the user showing the status of the request as it changes.  That sounds like exactly what's needed at first...But here's the thing: How is that click handler supposed to make the browser download the blob once the response has been delivered???
This is where I'm hoping to save others some time: As far as I can tell, there's really only one good way to trigger a download once a response is received that works in almost all browsers:  This, which is also explained here and here.  (There's also the Downloads API, but it won't work for users running Safari on any platform or users running Firefox on Android).
When I first saw that solution, I thought "That looks hacky.  Surely there's a better way!".  Then I wasted an hour searching for that better way.  And that's the point of this long post...At this point, it seems that browsers do not afford a simple way to trigger a download upon receiving a response to a POST request.  The best (albeit hacky) way is to URL.createObjectURL, then create a hidden <a> tag with the download attribute, and then call 'click' on that <a> tag.
